# Vaadin Charts (Highcharts) - Range Selector - Monthly Data

Tags: highcharts, vaadin, timeline, vaadin-charts

I provide monthly data to Vaadin Charts (example):
`{[01.08.2015;1], [01.09.2015;2], [01.10.2015;3], [01.11.2015;4], [01.12.2015;5], [01.01.2016;6]}`

Now I activate the timeline and want to use the range selector. Unfortunately the default "3m" for showing 3 months does not work. But as you see I clearly have data for 3 months.

Is there something I miss?

Here is an exemplary JsFiddle that used the data that is transferred from Vaadin to Highcharts and shows the described behaviour: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phqo4ppc/1/)

Comment: Is the data rendered correctly? More specifically, are the dates parsed correctly? Have you tried specifying the dates as %Y-%m-%d or so? Also is 3m the only button that doesn't work? Note you can make another button the default if you want.

Comment: Yes, the data is rendered correctly and show e.g. "Jan' 15" automatically on the x axis. Yes, 1m & 1y also do not work/are disabled. YTD is enabled, but does not show the data starting at the beginning of the year, but before.

Comment: Do you convert your x values (dates) into the timestamps? Could you paste your output json, used in Highcharts (after parsing) ?

Comment: I added an according fiddle. Thank you already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range selector buttons are enabled depending on the x-Axis range.
The buttons smaller than the x-Axis minimum range are disabled.

By default the minimum range of the x-Axis is five times the smallest interval between any of the data points.

Changing the x-Axis minimum range to 1 month (in milliseconds, so 28 days approximated) did the trick.

Source: [Vaadin Forums](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/12920760)